# SeleniumBasic VBA open edge in IE mode

Tags: vba, selenium, microsoft-edge

Trying to open a URL in an Edge Browser using SeleniumBasic (VBA). The problem is the secure website doesn't like two things. One SeleniumBasic-controlled website is in debug mode. Secondly, it requires the Edge Browser to be in IE mode.
I can open/work on other websites with no issues. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I found the answer. I was able to flow this link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/829365/vba-automation-with-edge-ie-mode.html

Answer (score 1):

using this link solved the problem. I was able to load into an Edge browser and work with the Dom Document directly. Using IE Mode.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/829365/vba-automation-with-edge-ie-mode.html